# Is Fiware-STH-Comet service compatible with NGSI-LD (linked data) format?

Tags: comet, fiware-sth-comet

I'm using Fiware's Orion LD service (https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD) in a Docker environment in order to store and manage data in the NGSI-LD format. I want to post a subscription to Orion-LD so that Fiware-STH-Comet will be notified of new values, but I'm not sure if STH-Comet service is also compatible with the NGSI-LD format. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

STH-Comet is not suppporting NGSI-LD at this stage